# VBA: How to write for and if together for following logic?

Tags: vba, excel

LOGIC:

```
For each cell in a range(column2)
if cell value = "spare"
  do nothing
if not 
   check whether each cell in range(column7) is empty
   if cell is blank do nothing
   if not
      counter++
```

Can someone please tell me how do I write this in proper VBA syntax?
Any help/hint is deeply appreciated.
Thank you so much in advance :)

Comment: I recommend reading up the VBA documentation. For-loops and conditions are fundamental stuff and I doubt you'll yield any salvageable results if you fail to understand the most basic principles.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each individualMember in MembersCollection
    'do something
Next 'individualMember
```

Your case:

```
Dim column2 as Range 'whole column, beware of overhead
Dim cell as Range 'one cell
Set column2 = sheets(1).columns(2)

For Each cell in column2.Cells
    If cell.value2 <> "spare" then 'not equal "spare"
        'check whether each cell in range(column7) is not empty
        If cell.offset(columnoffset:=5).Value2 <> "" then
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    ElseIf cell.value2 = "spare" And 1+1=2 Then
        'do another thing
    Else 'all other posibilities
        'do yet another thing
    End If
Next 'cell
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `If cell.offset(columnoffset:=5).Value2 <> "" `

Comment: @user007 Each `cell` is from `column2.Cells`. If we want also to compare this `cell` to a cell on same row, but different column (say column7), we can "Offset" `cell` by 5 columns. We get 2+5=7.